# Why delegation pattern doesn't work for a custom view of TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, view, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a project and using a storyboard to create a tab bar controller for my VC.
Then Inside the First controller, I hide the tab bar and add a custom view to the tab bar.

```
self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(customTabBarView)
```

This custom view has one view which contains the stack view with Three buttons, for the interaction I realize the delegate pattern but, this doesn't work, and I can't understand why. What I am do wrong? This is works if I create this view inside VC but not like a custom view class?

I do this "trick" because don't want to create a custom shape for my Tab Bar. My idea is to hide the tab bar controller then add a custom view with the buttons under the tab bar and use buttons to switch between controllers.

My custom view:

```
import UIKit

protocol GeneralViewButtons {
    func pressButton(number: Int)
}

class GeneralView: UIView {

    var delegate: GeneralViewButtons?

    var width: CGFloat!
    var height: CGFloat!
    var Yposition: CGFloat!
    var Xposition: CGFloat!
    
    lazy var TabBar: UIView = {
        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.149, alpha: 1.000)
        
        let viewGeneral = UIView()
        viewGeneral.frame = CGRect(x: Xposition, y: Yposition - height - (Xposition + (Xposition / 2)), width: width - (Xposition * 2), height: height)
        viewGeneral.backgroundColor = fillColor
        
        viewGeneral.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        viewGeneral.clipsToBounds = true
        viewGeneral.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        viewGeneral.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        viewGeneral.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        viewGeneral.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        viewGeneral.layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        return viewGeneral
    }()
    
    lazy var stack: UIStackView = {

        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width - (Xposition * 2), height: height)

        stack.layer.borderWidth = 1
        stack.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        stack.spacing = 30
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(but1)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(but2)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(but3)

        return stack
    }()
    
    lazy var but1: UIButton = {
        let but = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        but.backgroundColor = .red
        
        but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return but
    }()
    
    lazy var but2: UIButton = {
        let but = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        but.backgroundColor = .green
        
        but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return but
    }()
    
    lazy var but3: UIButton = {
        let but = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        but.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click3(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return but
    }()
    
    init(frame: CGRect, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.Yposition = y
        self.Xposition = x
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.addSubview(TabBar)
        self.TabBar.addSubview(stack)
        
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    @objc func click1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.pressButton(number: 1)
    }
    
    @objc func click2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.pressButton(number: 2)
    }
    
    @objc func click3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.pressButton(number: 3)
    }
    
}
```

My first VC:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, GeneralViewButtons {
    
    var customTabBarView: GeneralView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        createGradientLayer()
        hideTabBar()
        setupView()
        
    }
    //MARK: Delegate
    func pressButton(number: Int) {
        print(number)
    }

    
    func setupView() {
        customTabBarView = GeneralView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:0, height: 0),x: 20 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 70)
        
        self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(customTabBarView)
        
    }
    
    func createGradientLayer() {
        GeneralSettings.shared.background(mainView: self.view)
    }
    
    func hideTabBar() {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}
```

Comment: Mising customTabBarView.delegate = self in setupView. Put it after customTabBarView = GeneralView..........

Comment: Did you try explicitly extending the protocol `extension HomeVC: GeneralViewButtons{ pressButton ... }` ?

Comment: @Raja Kishan, I put customTabBarView.delegate = self after self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(customTabBarView) inside setupView and this is doesn't help (((

Comment: @Albert, If I understand you correctly, I did next: extension HomeVC: GeneralViewButtons {
    func pressButton(number: Int) {
        print(number)
    }
}, and this is didn't solved the problem.

Comment: I don't have any idea why it doesn't work,  and I have thoughts that will need draw a custom shape for the tab bar :(

Comment: @Ice try to add breakpoint inside the button click and check whether your button action is fired or not.

Comment: @RajaKishan, I did try it, and nothing happens, I can't understand why this code ( objc func click1(_ sender: UIButton)  ) inside the custom class doesn't execute, debugger can't help me.

Comment: Then it might be button view is overlapped by some other interection view. Use view debuger.

Comment: Could it be that the tabViewController is remaining hidden? But you're only hiding the tabBar inside it right, so it shouldn't be it. Though you have declared a TabBar variable inside your view. So with tabBar.isHidden=True you might be hiding something different than TabBar custom variable.

Comment: @RajaKishan, I did find the problem (https://imgur.com/lN9oNTw), this is because of my custom view with buttons, the custom view has other coordinates than my GeneralView, at the screenshot you will see the problem :). The realization of the delegate pattern works well but the need will be to change the coordinates of the view.

Comment: Thank you for help RajaKishan, Albert :)